Has a carbon fiber propeller ever broke with a bird strike?
Curious if a carbon fiber prop has broken(or considerably deformed) with a bird strike. Or maybe by something else other than an impact with the ground/crash.

I don't believe that the response to a prop strike (caused by a bird or anything else) would be different for a composite versus another material.
The company which manufactured one of the first composite blades has an info page which is primarily concerned with damage to what's attached to the propeller. Their guidance is to perform a complete inspection of the engine to ensure that other failures haven't been caused by the strike.
